# Attach a document to a WebEvent in Ektron?

Tags: file-upload, calendar, document, ektron

I'm fairly new to ektron. I want the users to be able to attach a document to a Calendar Event (such as an Agenda PDF or Minutes PDF) and I want to display that link, in the Event Details page, so users can view and download it. I don't see any way to do that on the Edit Event form inside the workarea. That doesn't make sense that they wouldn't include such a simple option by default. Do I really need to customize the workarea or create a smartform so users can upload documents along with their events? Can someone recommend the easiest approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this via the API. If you don't want to use the API, you could maybe use a content selector metadata item (this would require uploading the file first).